# How to increment a variable on repeated $_POST submissions?

Tags: php

The goal is to keep incrementing a variable on each page submission.

The code works to increment from 1 to 2 but on continued submissions, we never get to 3 or higher.

**CODE:**

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['bgChange'] = '';
if($i == '') { $i = 1; }
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $i++;
      $_SESSION['bgChange'] = $i;
 }
```

**CSS:**

```
    .background-full-image{
        background-color: #a1d3ff;
        background-image: url("images/background<?php echo $i; ?>.svg");
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

**Form that does the Submit:**

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="change banner bg color">
</form>
```

What confuses me is that we are able to increment but that we can only increment to the value of 2. Why does it not continue to increment on each Post?

Comment: Because you set $i to 1 each time …? `if($i == '')` will always be true, because you don’t set a non-empty value to $i anywhere before this.

Comment: Go and enable proper PHP error reporting! Then PHP can tell you when you try to access variables that were not declared previously.

Comment: @CBroe yes I see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!isset($_SESSION["bgChange"])) {
        $_SESSION["bgChange"] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION["bgChange"]++;
    }
  }
$i = $_SESSION["bgChange"];
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to adjust your code to make this work properly.

Comment: I realized I had a syntax error in there and was about to correct... Looks like you did it for me... My typing is atrocious!!!